# Reverse nested aggregation sum

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, aggregation

I'm trying to list the top travelers by city. The mapping is this

```
{
  "log" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "travels" : {
        "_ttl" : {
          "enabled" : true,
          "default" : 7776000000
        },
        "properties" : {
          "_type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "traveler" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "cities" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "count" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I managed to use the reverse nested aggregation, but I can't figure out where to put the sum aggregation. What I did was

```
{
  "aggs":{
    "travels":{
      "nested":{
        "path":"cities"
      },
      "aggs":{ 
        "top_ids":{ 
          "terms":{
            "shard_size":0, 
            "field":"cities.name"
          },
          "aggs":{
            "cities_to_traveler":{
              "reverse_nested":{},
              "aggs":{
                "top_travelers":{
                  "terms":{
                    "field":"traveler"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this? If I can provide more code, let me tell you.

EDIT: I want to sum the field count inside the cities nested field.

Comment: Hello, on what field do you want to sum?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I'm going to edit my question. I want to sum the count field.

Answer (score 1):

At each level of aggregation nesting, you can declare multiple aggregations.

In your case, if you want to sum the count for each city, you can declare your `sum` aggregation at the same level that the `cities_to_traveler`, like this :

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "travels": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "cities"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_ids": {
          "terms": {
            "shard_size": 0,
            "field": "cities.name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "cities_to_traveler": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggs": {
                "top_travelers": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "traveler"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "total": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "cities.count"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will have, for each city, the total count for all the travelers.

But, I'm not sure this is exactly what you want : I suspect you want for each city, the travelers ordered by descending count of their travel to this specific city.

In this case, you can look at the `top_hits` aggregations, ordering the results by `cities.count` ([documentation here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation)).